# Media query for 1440px width but not laptop screens?

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-resolution, mobile-development

I'm trying to make a media query to fix the body on 1440px only for large monitor screens, and to do this, I have this code:

```
@media (min-width:1440px) { 
     body {
       max-width:1440px
     }
}
```

This media query works fine, but I need to limit it **only** for a specific size of screen, like 23 inches, for example. I don't want to lose width on laptop screens.

I tried to make this using `max-resolution` but nothing seems to work.

So, can I create a media query that apply only with specific physical size of screen?

Thanks!

Comment: media query only works with resolutions instead of physical size of the screen. You've to adjust your code according to the resolution. For example. 1920x1080 or 1366x768 etc

Comment: @psychodeveloper Thanks! But there's a way to manipulate this media to not apply some styles with 1440px in larger screens only? Because we can have 1920x1080 on different monitor sizes.

Comment: No there's no way to manipulate physical devices only. The thing with physical devices is that some let's say 23" devices has 1920 x 1080p resolution where as some has 1440p resolution. In that case what will you prefer to do it? will you only target 1440p resolution on 23" screen or 1920p on 23" screen? That's why i'm saying the only way to adjust screen is with media queries and resolution sizes. I hope I've cleared your point.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting requirement! You could try to work with "resolution" inside the media query.

If you take your suggested 23 inches and the width of 1440 px you get around 62 dpi (dots per inch).

If you have higher dpi but still the min-width of 1440px, you should be on a smaller screen then 23 inches.

Try it out, I would be curios, if it works like expected.

```
@media (min-width:1440px) and (max-resolution: 62dpi) { 
    body {
        max-width:1440px
    }
}
```